# Entity Framework is not creating stored procedure object with Datatable type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have created a stored procedure with database table type `[dbo].[SeatTestUDT]` as input. But when I am refreshing Entity Framework object below Script is not getting created in `Model.tt`. Anyone faced this issue before? Please let me know if need more details.

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_SeatTest]
    @SeatBuilder [dbo].[SeatTestUDT] ReadOnly,
    @SeatPlanId int
AS
```

I want to pass list in `@SeatBuilder` parameter.

Thanks
Kiran

Comment: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/stored-procedure-in-entity-framework.aspx go through this tutorial. It will help you.

Comment: Thanks but that didnt help me either. I am trying to pass Type as input parameter, when I am looking at the Context, it is showing me only one input parameter. 'code' public virtual int usp_SeatTest(Nullable<int> seatPlanId)
        {
            var seatPlanIdParameter = seatPlanId.HasValue ?
                new ObjectParameter("SeatPlanId", seatPlanId) :
                new ObjectParameter("SeatPlanId", typeof(int));
    
            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("usp_ET_Inventory_Insert_Update_BP_SeatBuilder", seatPlanIdParameter);
        }'code'

Comment: stored procedure code?